# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi

Tags: apache-spark

**I am trying to run command in my linux shell to run spark examples, my spark version is spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7.My Spark cluster is running. So I dont't understand why was wrong. The following is my command :**

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master spark://node01:7077,node02:7077,node03:7077 --executor-memory 1G --total-executor-cores 2 /export/servers/spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.3.jar 100

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my quetion! Because the user and group of my spark installation directory is not root.I can run successfully after I change to root. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUVNN.png)